# Update a given list and its child objects using Salesforce Apex

Tags: apex

Update to question:

So I have created an invokable variable/method where the flow is passing the following parameters:

```
    public static void updateAccountOwner(List<TransferDetail> transferDetails) {
    for(TransferDetail td : transferDetails) { //THIS IS WHERE I AM COMPLETELY UNSURE ABOUT, AND I WAS TOLD A MAP WOULD BE BETTER TO BULKFY?
      for(Account a : td.accounts){


          //  Account a = new Account(Id = td.a.accountId, AccountOwner__c = td.a.newOwnerId);

          //  accounts.add(a);
      //  }
}
}
public with sharing class Request{
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<Account> accounts;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String newAccountOwnerName;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String oldAccountOwnerName;

    }
```

So each account in this list of accounts has opportunities of its own. But each account in the list will be updated with the same new owner, and also each opportunity will be transfered to the same owner

I have created a lightning flow where I have gotten a list of accounts based on criteria/information input by a user. I am trying to take this list of accounts and update its owner values and all the child contacts for each account in the list. So it is a list within a list. I know I have to use map for it but I am not sure what I am doing wrong/how to get started. Here is what I have:

```
public with sharing class LPP_UpdateOwner {
    public static void updateAccountOwner(List<List<Account>> accounts, newOwnerId){ //accounts would be the input list from the flow and is a list/colection of accounts that the flow queried. newOWNERID would be the name the user typed in the flow
    List<Account> aUpdated = new List<Account>(); //should this be a map??
    for( Account a: accounts){
          a.AccountOwner__c = newOwnerId;
          aUpdated.add(a)
    }
    update aUpdated;

        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppList = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Name from Opportunity where AccoundId IN :accounts.keySet() and Stage !='Closed Won']);
    List<Opportunity> oppToUpdate = new Opportunity();
    for (Opportunity opp :oppList.values()){
           opp.OwnerId = aUpdated.AccountOwner__c ? not sure what to put here(opportunity owner and account owner ha to be same, which is newNameId
           oppToUpdate.add(opp);
    }
    update OpptoUpdate;
```

So I am not sure if this is correct or not. Basically, I am trying to update all the accounts and each account's opportunity with a new name thats provided. Also, The reason why I am trying to use Maps is to avoid CPU Time limit because doing this in flow and process builder is casuing CPU time out errors.
Thank you

Comment: Are you saying that every account that is passed into this method is getting set to the same owner? I ask because you state about the accounts being passed in that `it is a list within a list` but you're only passing in a single owner Id so in your current setup, all those are going to be set to the same owner.

Comment: @nerdybeast yes. So I will have a list of accounts, all owned by John. I will pass that list of accounts and a name, lets say Mark. All accounts in that list need to be transferred to mark. Also, each account in the list has opportnities for example. Each of those opportunities will need to be owned now by Mark from John

Comment: Another problem im running into is that only one input parameter can be used in an @invokable method. so i can either pass a list of accounts or the name to the class

Comment: I left an answer below that I think is what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I would recommend renaming this class, "Request" is far too generic...
public class Request {

    @InvocableVariable
    public List<Account> accounts;

    @InvocableVariable
    public String newAccountOwnerName; //Is this the name of a user or the actual user Id???

    @InvocableVariable
    public String oldAccountOwnerName; //This property isn't needed...
}
```

```
public class InvocableLPPOwnerUpdate {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Assign New Owner' description='Will assign new ownership for the given account')
    public static void updateAccountOwner(List<Request> requests) {

        //You don't need a map in this situation, this approach is bulkified already because once you update
        //the owner on the Account, you can just read the owner from there when updating the opportunities
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        for(Request req : requests) {
            for(Account acct : req.accounts) {
                acct.AccountOwner__c = req.newAccountOwnerName;
                accounts.add(acct);
            }
        }

        update accounts;

        List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();

        for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Name, Account.AccountOwner__c FROM Opportunity WHERE AccoundId IN :accounts and Stage !='Closed Won']) {

            //No Map needed because we can get the correct owner from the linked Account that was already updated above
            opp.OwnerId = opp.Account.AccountOwner__c;

            opportunities.add(opp);
        }

        update opportunities;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. One thing I wanted to add was that instead of passing accountId in the invokable variables, the flow is passing a list of accounts. In that case, how would the code be modified?

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you are invoking `updateAccountOwner()`? I would like to see how the data is being passed in

Comment: I made some edits to the code. Thank you for your help

Comment: Okay I see what you're after now, I'll be editing my answer here shortly

Comment: the accountownername variable is an id actually. I should mofiy that varable name.

Comment: Hello @nerdy beast. Thank you so much for your help. One other thing was in your code, you have a nested for loop. Wouldn't that case CPU Limit errors?

Comment: I don't see any reason this would hit any CPU limits, we have Invocable methods doing way more logic than this and we've never hit a CPU limit error. That nested for loop is somewhat necessary in your case but even then, it's not doing any heavy CPU work at all, just iterating over a list so you should be just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much nerdy beast!